# Bash-style escape-underscore in Powershell

Tags: powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

In bash I frequently use the escape underscore shortcut:

```
subl somedir/file.sh
./(escape underscore)
```

Which fills in the last item from the last line, eg:

```
./(escape underscore)
```

Becomes:

```
./somedir/file.sh
```

**Is there a way I could set this up in powershell?**

(I'm using Powershell 5.1, ConEmu, and PSReadLine and PCSX)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Emacs mode with PSReadline, then <kbd>Esc</kbd> underscore does the right thing. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> also does the same thing and is bound in both Emacs and Windows modes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a similar function in Powershell (maybe just create one by yourself?), but you could go with an array. For example:

```
(Get-Childitem somedir)[-1]
```

It's not the same, but maybe a solution you could go with.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using Select-Object:

The Long version:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -Last 1
```

The short:

```
ls | select -l 1
```